# Replace exception logging with custom error message

Tags: android, exception, toast

I'm using Android's httpclient to connect to a domain as follows:

```
try {
            URL url = new URL("example.com");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            read(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now is it fine if I remove this line:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

And replace it with this:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect to domain.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

Or do I have to do something with the 'e' variable? In which case it'll be:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect to domain.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
        }
```

And if I do e.printStackTrace(), where does it print to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend catching only the thrown exception type (I think IOException in this case). Other exceptions may be for completely unrelated problems.

Yes, it's fine to replace the printStackTrace with the toast. Bonus tip: Just call

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect to domain.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and you can do it all in one line. :)

`e.printStackTrace()` will print to the standard logcat trace, which you can view with the `adb logcat` command (adb is part of the Android SDK).

Comment: Thanx, so `e.printstacktrace()` is only for dev/logging purposes, no point in having it in a published app? And thanx for the toast shortcut :)

Comment: It is only for dev/logging purposes, but I still think there is a point of having it in a published app. For network errors this may be excessively noisy, but it's often helpful to print out exceptions so that when customers report problems you can ask for logcat output or bugreport and debug from that.